# Unable to hold/pass reference of parent to the composition object

Tags: rust

In C++ it would something like `struct A` is composed of `struct B` and some function of `B` takes a pointer to the parent object `A`. So function of `A` calling that function of `B` will simply pass the `this` pointer to it. I'm trying this in Rust but failing to get it to work - this is what I want to achieve:

```rust
struct A<Type: T> {
    composition: Type,
    value: usize,
}

impl<Type> A<Type> where Type: T {
    fn new(obj: Type) -> A<Type> {
        A {
            composition: obj,
            value: 999,
        }
    }

    fn f(&mut self) {
        println!("Value: {:?}", self.value);
    }

    fn call(&mut self) {
        self.composition.f(&mut self);
    }
}

trait T {
    fn f(&mut self, &mut A<Self>);
}

struct B {
    value: usize,
}

impl B {
    fn new() -> B {
        B { value: 0, }
    }
}

impl T for B {
    fn f(&mut self, parent: &mut A<B>) {
        println!("B::f");
        parent.f();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let objA = A::new(B::new());

    // I want call sequence -> A::call() -> B::f() -> A::f()
    objA.call();
}
```

Note that i require mutability in all the functions although in example above it might seem that `&mut self` in most function parameters don't make much sense. How do it do this in Rust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot work because you're violating mutable aliasing requirements - you're trying to mutably borrow `A` and its substructure at the same time:

```rust
self.composition.f(self);
// roughtly equivalent to:
let c = &mut self.composition;  // borrow substructure
c.f(self /* borrow self */);
```

(I've removed explicit `&mut self` because it is incorrect (as it gives you `&mut &mut A<...>`, but it does not change the whole picture at all.)

This is a natural error in Rust framework. Suppose that `f` implementation on this particular composition `X` rewrites `composition` field on the passed object:

```rust
impl T for X {
    fn f(&mut self, a: &mut A<X>) {
        a.composition = create_x_somehow();
    }
}
```

And suddenly the object this method is called on is destroyed, and `self` is invalidated!

Naturally, the compiler prevents you from doing this *even if you know* that you don't modify `composition`, because such kind of knowledge cannot be encoded statically (especially given that this is a trait method which can be implemented by anyone having access to your trait).

You have essentially two choices in such situations:

- reformulate the problem so it does not require such architecture anymore, or
- use special language/library constructs to work around such static checks.

The second point is about using such things as `Cell`/`RefCell` (they are safe, i.e. don't require `unsafe` blocks, but they can panic at runtime - probably these can work in your case) or, if nothing else helps, dropping to raw pointers and `unsafe` code. But, frankly, the first option usually is better: if you design your code based on ownership semantics and aliasing rules enforced by the compiler, almost always the resulting architecture would be of much better quality.