# Outer object owning referencing inner object

Tags: design-patterns, rust, lazy-loading, object-lifetime

I need two objects; one object is a container which owns the second object.

```
struct OuterObject {
    foo: InnerObject,
}

impl OuterObject {
    /// Creates a new instance of OuterObject
    fn new() -> OuterObject {
        OuterObject {
            foo: InnerObject::new(false),
        }
    }

    /// Returns a mutable reference to the InnerObject
    fn get_foo(&mut self) -> &mut InnerObject {
        self.foo
    }
}

struct InnerObject {
    baz: bool,
}

impl InnerObject {
    /// Creates a new instance of InnerObject
    fn new(baz: bool) -> InnerObject {
        InnerObject {
            baz: baz,
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. But my `InnerObject` needs a way to reference the `OuterObject` that owns it.  This means I should pass a reference to the `OuterObject` into the `InnerObject`'s constructor.  But this means the `OuterObject`'s constructor doesn't compile, since `self` cannot be referenced in a constructor:

```
struct OuterObject {
    foo: InnerObject,
    vorg: u8,
}

impl OuterObject {
    /// Creates a new instance of OuterObject
    fn new() -> OuterObject {
        OuterObject {
            foo: InnerObject::new(&self, false), // fails; 'self' cannot be referenced in constructor
            vorg: 1,
        }
    }

    /// Returns a mutable reference to the InnerObject
    fn get_foo(&mut self) -> &mut InnerObject {
        self.foo
    }

    /// Returns OuterObject's vorg value
    fn get_vorg(&self) -> u8 {
        self.vorg
    }
}

struct InnerObject {
    blah: &OuterObject
    baz: bool,
}

impl InnerObject {
    fn new(blah: &OuterObject, baz: bool) -> InnerObject {
        InnerObject {
            blah: blah,
            baz: baz,
        }
    }

    /// Calculates something based on the state of the OuterObject that owns this InnerObject
    fn calculate_something(&self) -> u8 {
        self.blah.get_vorg() + 2
    }
}
```

Next plan: Since I can't reference `self` in a constructor, I attempted to use lazy loading instead:

```
struct OuterObject {
    foo: Option<InnerObject>,
    vorg: u8,
}

impl OuterObject {
    /// Creates a new instance of OuterObject
    fn new() -> OuterObject {
        OuterObject {
            foo: None,
            vorg: 1,
        }
    }

    /// Returns a mutable reference to the InnerObject
    fn get_foo(&mut self) -> &mut InnerObject {
        // lazy-loads the object
        if self.foo.is_none() {
            self.foo = Some(InnerObject::new(&self, false));
        }
        self.foo.as_mut().unwrap() // should always be safe
    }

    /// Returns OuterObject's vorg
    fn get_vorg(&self) -> u8 {
        self.vorg
    }
}

struct InnerObject {
    blah: &OuterObject
    baz: bool,
}

impl InnerObject {
    fn new(blah: &OuterObject, baz: bool) -> InnerObject {
        InnerObject {
            blah: blah,
            baz: baz,
        }
    }

    /// Calculates something based on the state of the OuterObject that owns this InnerObject
    fn calculate_something(&self) -> u8 {
        self.blah.get_vorg() + 2
    }
}
```

Now the compiler is concerned about lifetimes.  I have had difficulty finding documentation of how to indicate a lifetime of an object inside of an `Option`.  For instance, if it I write it this way, the compiler things that `InnerObject` needs to be a trait:

```
Option<InnerObject + 'a>
```

1) Is the desired relationship between `OuterObject` and `InnerObject` doomed to failure?

2) If not, is there a different design pattern I should be using?

3) If the design pattern I am pursuing is workable, how do I make it work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/29893978/155423; many others (search circular reference, parent reference, etc.).

Comment: [One question per question, please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).